# How to use the arrow keys in a custom TI program

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

I have looked at as many functions as I can and I still can't find one that lets you intercept the click of a TI arrow key click.

Comment: Can you please provide the TI model number?  Are you coding in Basic or Assembly?

Comment: It is an 83-silver and I am programming in whatever you use when you press the prog button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Basic programs, which are run with the "Prog" button, you'll need to call `getKey`, which returns a key code for the last button pressed.  The arrow buttons are mapped to codes `24`, `25`, `26`, and `34`.

More information is available at [TI-Basic Developer](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/userinput#toc4), underneath the heading "Reading Keypresses".

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I have looked into this for a while and I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I think this point might still be relevant.

If you are using the key input to move a character, or shift a value somehow, you are almost always better off avoiding `if-then-else` statements.

The fastest method is usually to do something like this:

```
:getkey -> A
:X+(A=24) -> X
:X-(A=26) -> X
:Y+(A=25) -> Y
:Y-(A=34) -> Y
```

which can be further condensed to:

```
:getkey -> A
:X+(A=24)-(A=26) -> X
:Y+(A=25)-(A=34) -> Y
```

Instead of dealing with the logic through the `if` statements, we utilize the fact that the `(A=24)` has a 'boolean' (0 or 1) value. So we add or subtract 1 if it is a certain value.

Setting limits is also fairly easy:

```
:getkey -> A
:X+(A=26)(X<=20)-(A=24)(X>0) -> X
:Y+(A=25)(Y<=15)-(A=34)(Y>=3) -> Y
```

So if `(X<20)` it will multiply by 1, but when X>=20, `(X<20)` will multiply by 0, negating the incriment.

I use another technique to help with selecting values in some of my programs: The left and right keys increment and decrement a variable by a different value than the up and down keys do. However, it requires some more logic.

```
:getkey -> A
:X+10(A=26)(X+10<=100)-10(A=24)(X-10>=0) -> X
:Y+(A=25)(Y<15)-(A=34)(Y>3) -> B
```

In this case, the left and right arrows go by tens, and the up and down go by ones. `(X+10<=100)` is used instead of `(X<100)` because the latter will be true if `X=99` so X can go up to 109. The former makes sure that adding ten will not exceed the limit.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it with the getkey command.

```
getkey (Store as) (Variable) A
while A=0
getkey (Store as) A
```

Then you can recall the variable A throughout the program. 
Each key has a number that is called through the getkey command.
So you can use that variable by,

```
If A = 25
...
If A != 25
...
```

(25 would be the up arrow)